# The argument type Data (where Data is defined in Sorotan.dart) can't be assigned to the parameter type Data (where Data is defined in DataModule.dart)

Tags: flutter, dart

### Here's the Error

> error: The argument type 'Data (where Data is defined in Sorotan.dart)'
> can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Data (where Data is defined
> in DataModule.dart)'.

---

Here is where the error Happened

```
GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {
                      //  Showing detail Page
                      Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (context) => DetailNewsScreen(
                             `data: data[index],` )));
                    },
```

### Here is the data module.dart

```
class Data {
  String id;
  String idKategori;
  String namaMasjid;
  String namaKategori;
  String judul;
  String gambar;
  String penulis;
  String waktu;
  String isi;
  int error;

  Data({
    this.id,
    this.idKategori,
    this.namaKategori,
    this.namaMasjid,
    this.judul,
    this.gambar,
    this.penulis,
    this.waktu,
    this.isi,
    this.error,
  });

  Data.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json){
    id = json['id_berita'];
    idKategori = json['id_kategori'];
    namaKategori = json['nama_kategori'];
    namaMasjid = json['nama_masjid'];
    judul = json['judul'];
    gambar = json['gambar'];
    penulis = json['penulis'];
    waktu = json['waktu'];
    isi = json['isi'];
    error = json["error"];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson(){

    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['id_berita'] = this.id;
    data['id_kategori'] = this.idKategori;
    data['nama_masjid'] = this.namaMasjid;
    data['nama_kategori'] = this.namaKategori;
    data['judul'] = this.judul;
    data['gambar'] = this.gambar;
    data['penulis'] = this.penulis;
    data['isi'] = this.isi;
    data['error'] = this.error;
    return data;
  }
}
```

### Here is the Sorotan.dart

```
class Sorotan {
  String _rc;
  String _pesan;
  List<Data> _data;

  Sorotan({String rc, String pesan, List<Data> data}) {
    this._rc = rc;
    this._pesan = pesan;
    this._data = data;
  }

  String get rc => _rc;
  set rc(String rc) => _rc = rc;
  String get pesan => _pesan;
  set pesan(String pesan) => _pesan = pesan;
  List<Data> get data => _data;
  set data(List<Data> data) => _data = data;

  Sorotan.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    _rc = json['rc'];
    _pesan = json['pesan'];
    if (json['data'] != null) {
      _data = new List<Data>();
      json['data'].forEach((v) {
        _data.add(new Data.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['rc'] = this._rc;
    data['pesan'] = this._pesan;
    if (this._data != null) {
      data['data'] = this._data.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class Data {
  String _idBerita;
  String _idKategori;
  String _namaMasjid;
  String _namaKategori;
  String _gambar;
  String _judul;
  String _isi;
  String _penulis;
  String _waktu;
  String _status;

  Data(
      {String idBerita,
        String idKategori,
        String namaMasjid,
        String namaKategori,
        String gambar,
        String judul,
        String isi,
        String penulis,
        String waktu,
        String status}) {
    this._idBerita = idBerita;
    this._idKategori = idKategori;
    this._namaMasjid = namaMasjid;
    this._namaKategori = namaKategori;
    this._gambar = gambar;
    this._judul = judul;
    this._isi = isi;
    this._penulis = penulis;
    this._waktu = waktu;
    this._status = status;
  }

  String get idBerita => _idBerita;
  set idBerita(String idBerita) => _idBerita = idBerita;
  String get idKategori => _idKategori;
  set idKategori(String idKategori) => _idKategori = idKategori;
  String get namaMasjid => _namaMasjid;
  set namaMasjid(String namaMasjid) => _namaMasjid = namaMasjid;
  String get namaKategori => _namaKategori;
  set namaKategori(String namaKategori) => _namaKategori = namaKategori;
  String get gambar => _gambar;
  set gambar(String gambar) => _gambar = gambar;
  String get judul => _judul;
  set judul(String judul) => _judul = judul;
  String get isi => _isi;
  set isi(String isi) => _isi = isi;
  String get penulis => _penulis;
  set penulis(String penulis) => _penulis = penulis;
  String get waktu => _waktu;
  set waktu(String waktu) => _waktu = waktu;
  String get status => _status;
  set status(String status) => _status = status;

  Data.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    _idBerita = json['id_berita'];
    _idKategori = json['id_kategori'];
    _namaMasjid = json['nama_masjid'];
    _namaKategori = json['nama_kategori'];
    _gambar = json['gambar'];
    _judul = json['judul'];
    _isi = json['isi'];
    _penulis = json['penulis'];
    _waktu = json['waktu'];
    _status = json['status'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['id_berita'] = this._idBerita;
    data['id_kategori'] = this._idKategori;
    data['nama_masjid'] = this._namaMasjid;
    data['nama_kategori'] = this._namaKategori;
    data['gambar'] = this._gambar;
    data['judul'] = this._judul;
    data['isi'] = this._isi;
    data['penulis'] = this._penulis;
    data['waktu'] = this._waktu;
    data['status'] = this._status;
    return data;
  }
}
```

### Detail News Screen

```
class DetailNewsScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final Data data;

  //Constructor
  DetailNewsScreen({this.data});

  @override
  _DetailNewsScreenState createState() => _DetailNewsScreenState();
}

class _DetailNewsScreenState extends State<DetailNewsScreen> {

  var listNews = List<ListBeritaResponse>();
  var data = List<Data>();

  void _getnews() async{
    Api.getNews().then((response){

      setState(() {
        this.data = response.data;
      });

    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _getnews();
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Detail Berita'),
        centerTitle: true,
        backgroundColor: Colors.red,
      ),
      body: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              SizedBox(
                height: 10.0,
              ),
              Image.network(
                widget.data.gambar,
                loadingBuilder: (BuildContext context, Widget child,
                    ImageChunkEvent loadingProgress) {
                  if (loadingProgress == null) return child;
                  return Center(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                      value: loadingProgress.expectedTotalBytes != null
                          ? loadingProgress.cumulativeBytesLoaded /
                          loadingProgress.expectedTotalBytes
                          : null,
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 10.0,
              ),
              Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    child: Text(
                    widget.data.judul,
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 17, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                ),
                  ),
              ]),
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical:1.h),
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    Text(
                    widget.data.penulis,
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12),
                  ),
                    Text(
                      widget.data.waktu,
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 10),
                    ),
                ]),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 1.h),
                  child: Text (widget.data.isi))
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

---

Please Any Idea how to solve this, Thank you!

Comment: Can you show us where are you importing Sorotan.dart and DataModule.dart?

Comment: @enzo Here is the dart file for both

Answer (score 0):

In the top of the file that's occuring the error there are some imports, such as

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
```

and so on. You can find there some imports that ends with Sorotan.dart and DataModule.dart. `data[index]` is returning a Data class present in one of those modules, I can't tell which one is. One thing you can do is renaming the Data class present in Sorotan to `SorotanData`, for example, and the Data present in DataModule to `DataModuleData`. Avoid creating classes with the same name in the same project.

Comment: error: The argument type 'SorotanData' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Data'. this happened

Comment: Can you tell me what are the types of `data` property from `DetailNewsScreen` and the `data` list you're using `data[index]`? They are incompatible.